# Best way to scale data

Tags: percentages, data-analysis

I have a dataset of percentages where the largest percentage is $82.2$ percent. I want to scale the dataset so that this maximum percentage becomes $100$ percent.

So, should I multiply all the percentages in the dataset by $\frac{100}{82.2}$ or should I add $17.8$ to all the percentages?

Would greatly appreciate any input!

Comment: It all depends the importance you want to give to lower percentages. If you shift by $17.8$ then there won't be anything lower than $17.8\%$, so if you want to keep a $0..100$ range it is better to stretch data by first method.

Comment: If you want a percentage of $0$ to remain $0$ (of course), then multiply.

Comment: Without knowing what you want to do with the results there is no way to answer the question.  Both approaches will make the maximum $100$.  Do you need to make sure the minimum is $0$?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

Because of your use of the word "scaling", I would say ratios should be preserved.  So you should multiply by $\frac{100}{82.2}$.

Adding $17.8$ to every score would be "translating" (or "shifting") rather than "scaling".